# In magento 2.0 how can i add new top links and remove existing one using xml

Tags: magento-2.0

app/design/frontend/Amydus/test/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">            
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Myblock" name="header.myblock">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="tlink.them" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/design/frontend/Amydus/test/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $custSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
?>
<?php switch ($block->getShowPart()):
    case 'welcome': ?>
        <!-- <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname ? $t('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().fullname) : '<?=$block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
        </li> -->
        <li><a style="margin: 3px 0 0 8px;" href="#"><span>CALL US AT - 9560740007</span></a></li>
        <li class=" login_seprator"> | </li>
        <li class="easy-return" ><a style="margin: 3px 0 0 8px;" href="#">  <span >EASY RETURNS & EXCHANGE</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class=" login_seprator"> | </li>                        
        <?php if(!$custSession->isLoggedIn()): ?>
            <li class="hi_li"><span class="guest-color">HI GUEST</span></li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li class="hi_li"><span><?php echo 'Hi '.$custSession->getCustomer()->getName(); ?></span></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <li class=" login_seprator"> | </li>
        <li class="first last top-links-a">
            <?php if($custSession->isLoggedIn()): ?>
                <a class="" title="Log Out" href="#">LOG OUT</a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <a class="" title="Log In" href="#">LOGIN</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li> 

        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "customer": {
                            "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php break; ?>

    <?php case 'other': ?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
    <?php break; ?>

<?php endswitch; ?>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**If you extended Luma Theme**

app/design/frontend/Amydus/test/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <!--  you can easly add New links with following code -->
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
               <!-- Contact us Link -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="contactus.link" after="register-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Constact Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact-us</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <!-- CMS Page Link Link -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="aboutus.link" after="contactus.link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">about Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">about-us</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

             <!--  you can easly Remove  links with following code -->
            <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
            <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      <!--for Sign In Link  -->
            <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          <!--for WishList Link-->
            <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->

        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**If you extended Blank Theme**

app/design/frontend/Amydus/test/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <!--  you can easly add New links with following code -->
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
               <!-- Contact us Link -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="contactus.link" after="register-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Constact Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact-us</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <!-- CMS Page Link Link -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="aboutus.link" after="contactus.link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">about Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">about-us</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

             <!--  you can easly Remove  links with following code -->
            <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
            <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      <!--for Sign In Link  -->
            <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          <!--for WishList Link-->
            <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->

        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Anyhow in Magento 2.1.3 the register-link disappears when using your solution. Any idea why?

Comment: How about moving those links inside the `<div class="header content"></div>` element, where the logo is? How would you do that?

Comment: to remove sign in, you have to use "authorization-link-login"

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface` block class, which allows you to sort links in the top.links block.

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="newsletter_subscription_top_link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Newsletter Subscription</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">newsletter/manage</argument>
        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```