# How to customize navigation in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, navigation

I am trying to modify the top navigation (the navigation that shows categories and subcategories as the main menu). I am using a free template(Ketty, from TemplateMonster) which in turn is based on Magento Blank Template. But, as i am very new to Magento, i am unable to figure out two things:

1. How to change location of menu. Currently it is coming next to the logo and before the customer menu, search box and shopping cart. I want to move it down just below it, in it's own block / container. But i am unable to understand the positions mentioned. Where is menu called from? How is it rendered there?
2. Is there a way to add other links from the CMS to the menu?

I tried looking around but, ,most are the resources are based on Magento 1.x hence could not find something substantial. Other issue is that I can't find enough time to read the documentation of Magento 2, which I am sure would provide all the answers, but due to lack of time, could not cover the length and breadth of the required section. Any help is much appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: anybody? even suggestions regarding appropriate Modules are a welcome help.

Comment: you can simply do it using default.xml in vendor/magento/magento_theme_default/design/frontend/magento_theme/layout/default.xml

Comment: @PGSutariya OP is asking for a solution in M2. The file you *might* be referencing is `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`, but it's not clear how to add links in a layout file.

Comment: @Design by Adrian You can add links in navigation visit: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/adding-a-non-category-link-to-the-navigation-links-in-magento-2


It is done by creating module as show in given link

If you want to add link in top links then visit this link: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92333/in-magento-2-0-how-can-i-add-new-top-links-and-remove-existing-one-using-xml

Answer (score 1):

To change a location of an element you can use: `move`

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final"/>
    <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price"/>
</body>
```

Look here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange

To add additional Links to the Topmenu you should have a look here:
[Magento 2: How can I add External URL in top menu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97120/magento-2-how-can-i-add-external-url-in-top-menu)

or here:
[Adding a non-category link to the navigation links in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/adding-a-non-category-link-to-the-navigation-links-in-magento-2)