# Override Default layout with module

Tags: magento2, layout

I have one module called Test_A. We can override any layout of **Module-theme** in **Test_A** by giving the same name.

Ex. **Module-theme/view/frontend/layouts/frontname_controller_action.xml**

**can be override by creating file**

**Test_A/view/frontend/layouts/frontname_controller_action.xml**.

But how can we override **Module-theme/view/frontend/layouts/default.xml** in My Module.

Why we have to create custom theme for it?

We can't modify any module's **default.xml** layout?

Comment: Why do you want override `default.xml` from theme into your custom module ?

Comment: @PЯINCƏ I want to add a block after top links

Comment: You want to add custom top links after core top links?

Comment: @26vivek Add it in `default_head_blocks.xml` as Magento recommend : `app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

Comment: @PЯINCƏ I want to remove top links block also.

Comment: @26vivek to remove top links block : `<referenceBlock name="top.links" remove="true" />`

Comment: @PЯINCƏ in which file (path) of Test_A module ?

Comment: @RohanHapani I want to replace top link with mine.

Comment: Refer this answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93853/

Comment: @RohanHapani My real question is how to over Defaul.xml layout through My **Module** not by Theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create **default.xml** in your module and add this below code :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <!-- remove core link -->
            <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />
            <!-- Add new link -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom.link" before="wish-list-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Custom Link</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">custom-path</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```